# Ignore result sets in SQL trigger execution

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers

I have an SQL trigger which calls a Stored Procedure. Something like this

```
Alter TRIGGER [dbo].[MyTrigger]
   ON       [dbo].[MyTable]
   AFTER    INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- Some t-sql

    -- Call Stored Procedure
        exec MyProc
END
```

Now the issue is procedure `MyProc` returns a result set, which is required by other part of the system, But I don't want that result set to be returned when this procedure is executed via this trigger, because result set is returning whenever I'm updating/inserting in `MyTable` which is the table on which trigger has been created and I don't want that result set every time on update/insert.

So Is there any possible solution of ignore the result set returned by trigger execution here? I have thought about a solution to pass a bit parameter to `MyProc` indicating whether it is being called via trigger or not and if that bit will be 1 (*means called via trigger*) I will not return result set from the procedure but this solution is affecting trigger as well as procedure both, I want something which can be done from trigger only without touching the procedure at all.

Answer (score 2):

if your stored procedure always returns only one set, you could suppress it my inserting into temporary table.

Example stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [MyProc]
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT getdate() as today;
END
```

Your trigger should look like this:

```
 Alter TRIGGER [dbo].[MyTrigger]
   ON       [dbo].[MyTable]
   AFTER    INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- Some t-sql

    -- Call Stored Procedure
    CREATE TABLE #myproc_tmp (
       today datetime
    )

    INSERT INTO #myproc_tmp
    Exec MyProc

END
```

Important note - if stored procedure's returned result set structure changes, you'll have to edit the trigger. Also if procedure returns large set of data, it'll consume extra server resources by inserting into #myproc_tmp table.
And lastly, if SP returns multiple sets of data with different structures, the INSERT INTO command will throw an error.