# How can I ignore the resultset of a stored procedure in a trigger?

Tags: mysql

My question is [basically this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24008163/ignore-result-sets-in-sql-trigger-execution) but for MySQL instead of SQL Server.

I have a stored procedure which returns a result set.

```
CREATE STORED PROCEDURE CreateFoo (input_id INT)
    DECLARE result_id INT;

    INSERT INTO FooTable (blah blah) VALUES (blah blah);

    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO result_id;

    INSERT INTO OtherTable (x, y, blah) VALUES (input_id, result_id, blah);

    SELECT result_id;
END
```

I have a trigger on another table

```
CREATE TRIGGER MyTrigger AFTER INSERT ON Bar
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    CALL CreateFoo (NEW.a);
    CALL CreateFoo (NEW.b);
END
```

But now when I insert into Bar I get

```
ERROR 1415 (0A000) at line 5365: Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger
```

I understand why this is happening, now I need to quietly ignore the resultsets from `CreateFoo`.

In SQL Server the answer is to create a temporary table and `INSERT INTO Temp CALL CreateFoo` but apparently you can't do this in MySql.

Is there a way to drop the resultset from the trigger in MySql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of is using `OUT` parameters (and this is actually the "clean" way of returning a result from a procedure, when it's just a single row).

Rewrite your procedure like this:

```
CREATE STORED PROCEDURE CreateFoo (IN input_id INT, OUT result INT)
    INSERT INTO FooTable (blah blah) VALUES (blah blah);
    SET result = LAST_INSERT_ID();
END
```

or

```
CREATE STORED PROCEDURE CreateFoo (IN input_id INT, OUT result INT)
    INSERT INTO FooTable (blah blah) VALUES (blah blah);
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO result;
END
```

You'd execute the procedure like this then:

```
CALL CreateFoo(5, @my_result);
```

When you need the last insert id, you can use it with

```
SELECT @my_result;
```

**in the same session.**

In your trigger of course you simply ignore the variable.

```
CREATE TRIGGER MyTrigger AFTER INSERT ON Bar
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    CALL CreateFoo (NEW.a, @variable_you_donT_care_about);
    CALL CreateFoo (NEW.b, @variable_you_donT_care_about);
END
```

Read more about `IN`, `OUT` and `INOUT` parameters [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html).

Comment: So at the PDO level, would it be like this? `$q=$db->prepare("CALL CreateFoo(?,@tmp)"); bind_and_execute($q); $q=$db->prepare("SELECT @tmp");` ?

Comment: I'm no programmer, sorry :) Try it out.

Comment: @spraff: See [Prepared statements and stored procedures: Example #4 Calling a stored procedure with an output parameter](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php#example-1009).